# How to call and HTTP route from express controller?

Tags: api, express, meanjs, controllers

Hi i need some help for this issue, I need to run:

```
 exports.someFunction = function () {
   // i need call a route like this.
   app.route('api/getdata');
};
```

I need call some route in express function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `/api/getdata` returns some sort of data (in a format like JSON) you need to use. In that case, it is pretty simple, just use Node's excellent `unirest` library. I find Node's `http` a little advanced for this case. Assuming that this is a GET request, it would look something along the lines of:

```
unirest.post('http://example.com/api/getdata').end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Of course, you can use Node's `http.get` if you wanted or any other HTTP library you like.